How can I find the prime factors p and q given d, n, and e=65537 in RSA encryption?
I'm working with RSA encryption and I know the following values:

e=65537 (the public exponent)
n (the modulus, which is the product of two primes p and q)
d (the private exponent)

I am trying to figure it out if it is possible to get the values p and q and I know they range from 1 to 2^1337 -1.
I also know the code in which the values got generated (but I was only given n and d.
class RSA:
    def __init__(self, bits):
        self.p = getPrime(bits)
        self.q = getPrime(bits)
        self.n = self.p * self.q
        self.e = 0x10001
        self.phi = (self.p-1)*(self.q-1)
        self.d = pow(self.e, -1, self.phi)


Please take some time to read the [help], especially What topics can I ask about here? and What types of questions should I avoid asking? Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask].

This question is better asked over at the cryptography stackexchange site.

Why do you want to get p and q, when you already have n, d and e?

It's already been answered at the cryptography stackexchange site, and here as well. I'm pretty sure I've answered here sometime in the past, thought I can't seem to find it now.

Here is one link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2921406/238704
